# Object Values sorting with umulate order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to sort the json response object array in specific order like if the object contains Umlaute words/characters

```
object {
  item: 1,
  users: [
   {name: "A", age: "23"}, 
   {name: "B", age: "24"},
   {name: "Ä", age: "27"}
 ]
}
```

Expected name sorting is A, Ä and B.

when trying to sort with localecompare().

```
object.sort(function (a, b) { return a.localeCompare(b); });
```

Getting the error like `object.sort` is not a function. Is there anyway to sort the object array.

Comment: no you cannot do that. `sort` is an array method and you can never guarantee the order of object keys

Comment: I understand but any alternative for it?

Comment: Looking at your example, You do have an array of objects and it is possible to sort this array using `sort`. Shouldn't you do `object.users.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`.

Comment: I have tried object.users.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) but throws an error like a.localeCompare is not a function

Comment: it's a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) not a.localeCompare(b.name))

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. It is working great now. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the property of the object for sorting.

```js
var object = { item: 1, users: [{ name: "A", age: "23" }, { name: "B", age: "24" }, { name: "Ä", age: "27" }] };

object.users.sort(function (a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how do you know he want to sort the user?

Comment: @brk, *"Expected name sorting is A, Ä and B. "*.

Comment: @klmuralimohan, does the above works for you? do you use `a.localeCompare`? `a` is an object, not a string, like `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You must apply the `sort()` function to the array, not the outer object. Objects don't have that method and in the general case key order is not guaranteed, anyways. For "ordered" data always use arrays, not objects!

This is an example that uses the `o.users` array. The output `n` is also an array.

**NOTE**: never abuse reserved keywords as variable names. You use `object` as a variable name, it is strongly recommended to not do so! I've replaced it with `o`. Albeit `object` is not a reserved keyword, `Object` (with capital `O`) is. And the two are easily confused.

```js
var o = {
  "item": 1,
  "users": [
    { "name": "A", "age": "23" },
    { "name": "B", "age": "24" },
    { "name": "Ä", "age": "27" }
  ]
};

var n = o.users.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, "de"));

console.log(n);
```